# Issue with setting up nginx for wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a following wordpress nginx configuration in my /etc/nginx/sites-available/wordpress:

```
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjs;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }


    location /wordpress {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri $uri/wordpress/ /wordpress/index.php$is_args?$args;

            location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;
                    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            }
    }
```

As you can seem, there is a static, NextJS-based frontend for WordPress. And generally, it works just great. There is this one quirk that does not work, though, and I'm not sure if it is a WordPress issue or a Nginx issue.

- When the user navigates to /wordpress, then we see content from wordpress, which is fine
- When the user navigates to /wordpress/graphql, then the grahpql endpoint is working just fine
- **When the user navigates to /wordpress/wp-admin, then the things break. There is a redirect loop, and the brauser reports that the site is not redirecting properly and so on**.
- when the user navigates to /wordpress/wp-admin/index.php, then everything works fine though.

So where does this come from? Is it a Nginx thing? WordPress thing? How do I fix this?

Edit 1: Added curl -vvv output:

```
C:\Users\alank>curl -vvv https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-admin
*   Trying 194.204.13.171:443...
* Connected to mydomain.ee (194.204.13.171) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /wordpress/wp-admin HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.ee
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< date: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 10:19:10 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< link: <https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< x-redirect-by: WordPress
< location: https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-admin/
<
* Connection #0 to host mydomain.ee left intact
```

Edit 2: curl -vvv with trailing slash:

```
C:\Users\alank>curl -vvv https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-admin/
*   Trying 194.204.13.171:443...
* Connected to  mydomain.ee (194.204.13.171) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET /wordpress/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: mydomain.ee
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
* schannel: remote party requests renegotiation
* schannel: renegotiating SSL/TLS connection
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection renegotiated
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
< date: Tue, 22 Aug 2023 11:13:01 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
< link: <https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
< x-redirect-by: WordPress
< location: https://mydomain.ee/wordpress/wp-admin/
< 
* Connection #0 to host mydomain.ee left intact
```

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of `$uri/wordpress/` in your `try_files` statement. I would expect to see `$uri/`. Also, do you have `index index.php;` or `index index.html index.php;` defined somewhere?

Comment: I have `index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
` in the nginx config - updated the initial config block. As for the purpose of $uri/wordpress/- I'm no server guru. I copied the conf from some example or another, saw it worked and saw no need to change it further.

Comment: Could you test with `curl -vvv https://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin` what the redirect loop is?

Comment: @EsaJokinen - added the curl output to the post.

Comment: So, `https://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin` forwards to  `https://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/` with a slash, and what happends next?

Comment: @EsaJokinen added the curl output with trailing slash too.

Comment: I did some more googling. Could it be this issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/170165/wordpress-wp-admin-https-redirect-loop AS I understand (not being an actual server guy), that the site sits behind a load balancer (that was configured by someone else.

Comment: On the other hand, `/wordpress` doesn't? But indeed the second `curl` shows the problem. I can't see anything in this configuration causing this. Maybe Wordpress interprets it differently and performs some internal redirection?

Comment: I guess we at least established that Wordpress is the cause of this, not my Nginx config. That is a step forward, too, in my book.

Comment: looks like a typical redirect loop- check both the Nginx error and access logs, as well as the WordPress debug logs, to get more insights into the issue

Comment: Adjust your location /wordpress block as follows:
location ^~ /wordpress/ {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php$is_args$args;
}
The ^~ modifier ensures that this location block is chosen as a match if the prefix matches, and no regular expression matches, which is a good measure to ensure the /wordpress/wp-admin and /wordpress/wp-admin/ requests end up in the same block.

Comment: Nginx access and error logs do not give any information. The curl that @EsaJokinen had me do provide more insight. I'll try the nginx settings changes, but it seems that both requests end up in the same block anyway. That is not the problem. AS you can see both curl requests have same response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/wordpress/wp-admin/` redirects to itself.

Have you tried using the exact example for this use case from the official [Nginx WordPress](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/) documentation?

Here, modified for your use case where it should not affect `.php` outside `/wordpress/`:

```
location /wordpress {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
        }
}
```

Your `fastcgi_split_path_info` differs from this recommendation.

Comment: I'll test it out. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, this works. Almost exactly as it should. The only problem is that /wordpress/wp-admin path does not redirect to /wordpress/wp-admin/ now. If I curl the URL, then the response is 301 permanent redirect to trailing slash, but the browser just keeps loading and loading and loading and loading and loading...

Comment: And I'm very sorry the bounty expired. I was just too busy to check the fix you proposed. Sorry again.

Comment: That's ok. I already have more than enough reputation for all the [privileges](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges).

Answer (score -1):

one can try using following in the location block (feel free to adjust path as needed) i.e. `/wp-admin/index.php?$args` depending on your environment/setup:

```
try_files $uri  $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

REF:

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/
- https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/nginx/

Comment: That's not going to help when wordpress is not configured at the root of the path